# Connection to a oracle database

Tags: oracle, hacklang

This one seems like it should be obvious but could I get some guidance on how you use HHVM and Hack to connect to an Oracle DB? Has anyone done this? If so could we provide some guidance on this? I am sure someone has done this in the past.

Apologies in advance if this has already been answered - I did try to search for it but can't find anything related to connecting to a db?

Comment: Do you mean "Oracle Database" the product? If so, unfortunately, HHVM's database support is a little slim. Consulting [the list of extensions](https://docs.hhvm.com/hhvm/extensions/introduction), the only databases with official extensions are mysql, sqlite, postgres, redis and mongo. The next best thing is the HHVM docs' [guide to developing extensions](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Extension-API).

Comment: Yes I mean the Oracle Database - sorry should have been more clear.

Comment: No worries. Unfortunately, you might be out of luck with connecting to Oracle directly from HHVM. Depending on how necessary HHVM is in your stack, you could use a separate worker to run your queries and talk through Redis, or develop your own extension, perhaps referring to the official MySQL extension re: how they handle ODBC.